# Extract Date with different format from a text field

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I am trying to extract the date from a text field, the date could be in the format of `m/d/yy`, `mm/d/yy`, `m/dd/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`.  I would like the query to return the date as `Datetime` (ideally in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`), here are some examples:

Table name: tblNote
Field name: Notetext

Note Summary: 1/2/99 Monday ...

Report: 02/3/06 Tuesday ...

User called in: 3/11/98 Wednesday...

Client feedback: 04/22/15 Thursday....

Is there an easy way to accomplish this, thanks in advance!

Here is my table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myNote](
    [NOTETEXT] varchar NULL
)

INSERT INTO mynote VALUES
('Note Summary: 4/1/17 Monday'),   -- m/d/yy
('Report:   04/1/17 Tuesday'),  -- mm/d/yy
('User called in:   4/01/11 Wednesday'),  -- m/dd/yy
('Client feedback:  04/01/17 Thursday'), -- mm/dd/yy
('Defendant Note:     7/13/11... deft. deceased... case withdrawn... EJG')

SELECT notetext,
        CONVERT(Date, SUBSTRING(notetext, CHARINDEX('/',notetext)-2,8), 1) As DateAsDate
FROM myNote

--Result:
notetext    |   DateAsDate
-----       |   -----
Note Summary: 4/1/17 Monday | 2017-04-01
Report: 04/1/17 Tuesday | 2017-04-01
User called in: 4/01/11 Wednesday   | 2011-04-01
Client feedback: 04/01/17 Thursday  | 2017-04-01
Defendant Note:     7/13/11... deft. deceased... case withdrawn... EJG  | 2011-07-13

Everything works great so far, however, I copied a record that's from my conversion table, it looks identical to the 5th record I scripted, however, when I ran the same query, I am getting the following error.

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is what's in my table now:

Note Summary: 4/1/17 Monday
Report: 04/1/17 Tuesday
User called in: 4/01/11 Wednesday
Client feedback: 04/01/17 Thursday
Defendant Note:     7/13/11... deft. deceased... case withdrawn... EJG
Defendant Note:     7/13/11... deft. deceased... case withdrawn... EJG

Here is a copy of my database with the table, you should be able to restore the db and duplicate the issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MJBFXS2FWfWVBBdVhkS1R6RG8/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `date` type for a field that is meant to store date information?

Comment: That's exactly what we are trying to do, this is from a legacy system that we are trying to convert the data from, we are trying to get the date from the field and store it in a separate Datetime field.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I seemed to be able to use SUBSTRING(NOTETEXT, CHARINDEX('/',NOTETEXT)-2,8) to get the date, but when I tried to convert them to Datetime, I was getting the error, it appears that it doesn't take different date format (e.g. it works for mm/dd/yy but not m/dd/yy).

Comment: I am getting errors when I try to CAST the string to Datetime on some records.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lucky for you the format is pretty much the same, it only defers in the number of digits for month or day.
This means you can simply use `CONVERT`, since SQL Server will know how to handle this.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    DateAsString varchar(8)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('4/1/17'),   -- m/d/yy
('04/1/17'),  -- mm/d/yy
('4/01/17'),  -- m/dd/yy
('04/01/17') -- mm/dd/yy
```

The query:

```
SELECT  DateAsString,
        CONVERT(Date, DateAsString, 1) As DateAsDate
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
DateAsString    DateAsDate
4/1/17          01.04.2017 00:00:00
04/1/17         01.04.2017 00:00:00
4/01/17         01.04.2017 00:00:00
04/01/17        01.04.2017 00:00:00
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/IMHSO3434)

Comment: Hi Zohar,

Thanks for your response! I had tried 'Convert' but for some reason, it's not working for all my records. I know if you add the data with the script, it's working without a problem, however, when I copy some records from my table, the query doesn't work for some records, it's very strange.

Comment: please don't paste cofe into comments. Edit your question instead.